# AngularJS directive not working on IE even with fixes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs

I use some directives with `replace: 'E'` to use JQueryUI buttons and dialog in a website. My directived are named uiButton and modal.

The pages are loaded using a javascript function triggered when a link is clicked (don't designed this mess...).

The only way I made AngularJS to work on thoses included pages is by manually bootstraping :

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('contentDiv')).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('contentDiv'), ['myApp']);
});
```

When AngularJS is loaded and used with ng-app, directly in the index.php page, my directives actually works even in IE. I used the `document.createElement(directive)` fix.

However, with the import function, the directives works in Chrome, FF but not in IE8, where it makes 3 sliblings, like written in the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie).

Unfortunately, IE support is needed.

Anyone have an idea to fix this problem ?

Comment: You may consider bypassing such problems of "IE" doesn't know my super element" by using directives as data attributes. Does IE report any console error?

Comment: No errors on the IE console. Using attributes does work, I keep them as a last chance.

Comment: Are `document.createElement(directive)` also called dynamically ? All of them may need to be called before page load.

Comment: The `document.createElement('');` are certainly the solution, but I've tried to place them at every possible place in the code and yet the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it in the head of your index.html like that throught an HTML comment :

```
<!doctype html>
 <head>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <script>
        document.createElement('poster');
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Refer to this : http://www.befundoo.com/blog/angularjs-directives-in-ie8/